# How to show the list of Subjects of a Student not the Linking Class of StudentSubject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

This is my **Student** class:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // omit unnecessary codes

    public IList<StudentSubject> Subjects{get; set;} = new List<StudentSubject>();
}
```

This is my **Subject** class:

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // omit unnecessary codes

    public IList<StudentSubject> Students{get; set;} = new List<StudentSubject>();
}
```

And now, I have this class that links the two upper mentioned classes which is the **StudentSubject**

```
public class StudentSubject
{
    public string StudentId {get; set;}        
    public Student Student {get; set;}

    public string SubjectId {get; set;}        
    public Subject Subject {get; set;}
}
```

In my repository, I can successfully add a *Subject* to a *Student* using this code:

```
student.Subjects.Add( new StudentSubject { SubjectId = subject.Id });
```

And my view looks like this:

```
return await _context.Students
    .Where(p => p.Id == id )
    .Select(p => p.Subjects)
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, this results to:

```
[
    [
        {
            "studentId": "student1",
            "student": null,
            "subjectId": "subject1",
            "subject": null
        }
    ]
]
```

Instead of my expected result which is suppose

```
[
    [
        {
            "subjectId": "subject1"
            // subject information
        },
        {
            "subjectId": "subject2"
            // subject information
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Did you intend to add a StudentSubject with no student ID? `student.Subjects.Add( new StudentSubject { SubjectId = subject.Id, StudentId = student.Id });` ?

Comment: _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the rows in the join table (`StudentSubject`).  That's why you're getting an array of arrays in the JSON result.  You really want the rows from the other side of the join, the `Subject` table.  You can use the LINQ `SelectMany` method to move all the separate list results into a single list, then a second `Select` to get the `Subject` for each row in the join table.  This is actually easier to read in query syntax

```cs
return (from student in _context.Students
        where student.Id == id
        from studentSubject in student.Subjects      // This is the query syntax for SelectMany
        select studentSubject.Subject)
       .ToListAsync();
```

If you prefer, here's the method syntax

```cs
return await _context.Students
    .Where(p => p.Id == id )
    .SelectMany(p => p.Subjects)
    .Select(p => p.Subject)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ query selects a single `List<StudentSubject>` object, and your expected results indicates you want a collection of Subjects:

```
context.Students.Single(stu => stu.Id == 12345)
  .Subjects.Select(stusub => stusub.Subject);
```

Comment: Nice one for another working LINQ query but this List wont have a `GetAwaiter`

Comment: Does it have to? Import Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and use SingleOrDefaultAsync then? It was more about speaking to the problem that CodeRed had pulled the StudentSubject object rather than the Subject